# How to get the corresponding object from collection view when a button is pressed?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, binding, collectionview

I have a `CollectionView` and each item contains 2 buttons. Edit and delete. I want to delete or edit the item when the button is pressed. But the problem is how can I get that particular item's corresponding object when the inside button is pressed? Because the selection mode is set to none, and pressing the button won't select the item either. So I can't access the item using by following -
`(Model)collView.SelectedItem.Constructor.... (//Do something where x:Name = collView)`.

Here is something I tried -

```
<CollectionView x:Name="RequestCollectionView"
                SelectionMode="None"
                Margin="0,35,0,0">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="users:Student">
            <StackLayout>
                    <Label x:Name="studentName"
                           Text="{Binding Name}"
                           Margin="0,25,0,0"/>
                    <Button x:Name="acceptBtn"
                            Clicked="AcceptBtn_Clicked"
                            HeightRequest="24" 
                            WidthRequest="24"/>
                    <Button x:Name="rejectBtn"
                            Clicked="RejectBtn_Clicked"
                            HeightRequest="24" 
                            WidthRequest="24" 
                            Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

I tried the following approch but it didn't work ->

```
private void AcceptBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Here I get NullRef Exception
    testText.Text =
        ((Student)RequestCollectionView.SelectedItem).Name;
   // var t = (Student)sender; //Invalid Cast
}
```

> If the title is not appropiate, suggest or edit please. I couldn't find the appropiate title for this question. Pardon me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the `BindingContext`

```
private void AcceptBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = (Button) sender;
    var student = (Student)btn.BindingContext;

    testText.Text = student.Name;

}
```

Comment: it says `System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'` at 3rd line :(

Comment: according to the code you posted, `Student` should be the correct type.  If it isn't you need to use the debugger to determine what type it thinks it really is.

Comment: actually, I can't cast this line -> `var btn = (Button) sender;` :(

Comment: what type does it think `sender` is?

Comment: Actually my bad, I was using ImageButton in the real code. Nevermind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add CommandParameter to your buttons

```
<Button x:Name="acceptBtn"
        Clicked="AcceptBtn_Clicked"
        HeightRequest="24" 
        WidthRequest="24"
        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
<Button x:Name="rejectBtn"
        Clicked="RejectBtn_Clicked"
        HeightRequest="24" 
        WidthRequest="24" 
        Margin="0,0,15,0"
        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
```

Event Handling

```
private void AcceptBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(sender is Button b && b.CommandParameter is Student student)
    {
       testText.Text = student.Name;
    }
}
```